# ttyACM0 is missing

Tags: ubuntu, arduino

I've been searching for a solution, but couldn't find it here or wherever. I don't know if it's exactly programming, as is about **arduino**, but here it goes.
I have a **FREEDUINO UNO** board (pretty similar to ARDUINO UNO, but from bq), which perfectly worked on **Arduino 1.6.5** two days ago, BUT today it doesn'. Apparently, the port is missing, the port itself was ***ttyACM0***, in /dev/. In fact I have no option of choosing a port available. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I already tried:

- all searching methods in /dev/ of ***ttyACM0*** and ***ttyUSB0*** in the terminal, it's not there.
- group
- **dialout** (and permisses and all about this option, is done)
- lsusb
- reboot
- start from root
- unplug and plug, and plugging in different ports

I would appreciate every solution which doesn't implies "unistall and install the Arduino" "have another version" or even "another ubuntu", cause it worked fine, and it can verify code and all of that. Also my board blinks when connected so is not dead. I hardly think 16u2 is dead.

Help please, and thank you!

Comment: Do you see a diff between `lsusb` without the Arduino plugged and `lsusb` with the Arduino plugged ? Do you have some lines about your Arduino on `dmesg` ?

Comment: not diff in the _lsusb_ with and without unplug. which worries me, yep. also, nothing about arduino in _dmesg_ either. is this last, should i look for something else? like, can something else be affected by this?

Comment: Can you try on other PC to check if the problem is your PC or the Arduino ? If you have a prog loaded on your arduino, when you plug the arduino does it work as expected ?

Comment: hi @Ôrel yeah, I thought of that unfortunately I don't have other PC.

Comment: Does the arduino react when you plug it ?

Comment: it lights, with a red blinking. That's the reason I said I don't think the problem is the board itself :/

Comment: Take a look here http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/153/how-to-check-my-arduino-board-is-working-or-dead You will found more help on http://arduino.stackexchange.com  Your arduino have power but usb interface can be down

Comment: thank you! I'll take a look

Comment: Hi so, after a while (I checked that page too) it doesn't work. any more ideas? :( I have this arduino and all and really want to use it

Comment: Have you tried on a different computer ?

Comment: as I said before, I have no other PC currently :(

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem using **Data & Power USB Cable**

Port ttyACM0 not appear if you only use Power USB Cable

Answer (score 4):

This took me hours to figure out but my power/data cable was not pushed all the way in. Even though light was on. Making sure it is inserted properly. Fixed everything.

Comment: Oh my gosh! I can't believe it was something related to pushing a little bit the cable! I spent hours trying to figure what was the problem..

Answer (score 1):

When you have not plugged in anything to the USB port, you will not see the port in the list. So plugin something (mouse, device or even your Arduino) and the ACM will pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have selected the correct port in Tools-->Port.

Select the port that has /dev/ttyUSB0 (or something like it) in its name. For Linux users

Answer (score 0):

In my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS  I noticed that ttyACM0 appears to /dev folder after I have plugged my Arduino uno to USB port.  To get the Tools/SerialPort active I say in terminal > sudo chmod 766 /dev/ttyACM0
I am not sure is that secure enough, but because the ttyACM0 disappears from dev list when I blug my Arduino uno off, therefore there is maybe no secure risk to change the rights of the ttyACM0 . If any doubt of risk, then better to use Arduino IDE in offline (i.e. logging out from network).